# Populate UITableView with NSMutableArray saved with NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my application I have an UITextView, which is populated at runtime when I insert new data via an Alert Controller. To print this use data:

```
NSArray * textfields = alertController.textFields;
                
UITextField * urlfield = textfields [0];
UITextField * titlefield = textfields [1];
UITextField * categoryfield = textfields [2];
                
FeedInfo * newFeed = [[FeedInfo alloc] init];
NewFeed.feedURL = urlfield.text;
NewFeed.feedTitle = titlefield.text;
NewFeed.feedCategory = categoryfield.text;
                
[Self.feedArray addObject: newFeed];
[Self.tableView reloadData];
```

Where feedArray is a defined class model:

```
@interface FeedInfo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedURL;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedTitle;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedCategory;
@end
```

Next, I print the data from feedArray inside the IUTableView with:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
FeedInfo *feedToShow = [self.feedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = feedToShow.feedTitle;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = feedToShow.feedCategory;
return cell;
```

> OK. Up to here everything works fine.

Now the problem is that before I quit the application, I want to save all the cells in the UITableView, because when the re-opening must still have all the inserted data.

I was thinking of saving all the feedArra array (1st class of this topic) by inserting this piece of code after `[self.feedArray addObject: newFeed];` and before `[self.tableView reloadData];`

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults
[UserDefaults setObject: self.feedArray forKey: @"feedArray"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Within the viewDidLoad method instead:

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
Array = [userDefaults objectForKey: @ "feedArray"];
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
FeedInfo *feedToShow = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = feedToShow.feedTitle;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = feedToShow.feedCategory;
```

But it throws an `Exception`:

```
 RSSReader[47834:2470261] [User Defaults] Attempt to set a
 non-property-list object ("<FeedInfo: 0x600000235200>" ) as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key feedArray 2017-07-18 11:00:13.652
 RSSReader[47834:2470261] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
 list object (
     "<FeedInfo: 0x600000235200>" ) for key feedArray'
```

Comment: no you can't directly save NSArray into User Defauilt use , NSKeyedArchiver

Comment: Use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and make the `NewFeed` class `NSCoding` compliant.

Comment: @Dhiru @Larme ok thanks, but if i use NSKeyedArchiver like `NSData * data  = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newFeed];`
 , in cellForRowAtIndexPath i have:     `FeedInfo *feedToShow = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and i have this error:  **No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'**. How to retrive data in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: data is a `NSData` covert `NSData` to `NSArray`

Comment: @Dhiru ok thanks, i try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You model (Feed) should confirm to `NSCoding protocol` to Archive and UnArchive the data.

**FeedInfo.h**

```
@interface FeedInfo : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedURL;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedTitle;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *feedCategory;

@end
```

**FeedInfo.m**

```
@implementation FeedInfo

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];

    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.feedURL = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"feed_url"];
    self.feedTitle = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"feed_title"];
    self.feedCategory = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"feed_category"];

    return self;

}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    [coder encodeObject:_feedURL forKey:@"feed_url"];
    [coder encodeObject:_feedTitle forKey:@"feed_title"];
    [coder encodeObject:_feedCategory forKey:@"feed_category"];
}

@end
```

**Store to Userdefault**

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.feedArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"feedArray"];
```

**Retrive from UserDefault**

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"feedArray"];
NSArray *feedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand. The only doubt that comes to me is this: when do I re-open the application as I load the UITableView again? I must enter `NSData * data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "feedArray"];
     NSArray * feed = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];` Inside the **viewDidLoad and then** ? How do I modify the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: you have to assign to table view data source. `self.feedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];` Everything will work as usual

Comment: EDIT: WORK!! Mmh..have inserted `self.feedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: date];` Within the viewDidLoad but does not save anything:|

Comment: just make sure your array `self.feedArray` is not empty. After unarchive the data

Comment: Ok thanks. I have the last question: if, for example, I wanted to delete a cell inside the tableview, how can I delete it from NSUserDefault?

Comment: Once cell deleted remove the object from self.feedArray and save the feedArray again to UserDefault

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149462/discussion-between-taprolano-and-subramanian).

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Then:
1) I open the app, and if I insert the data into the controller alerts, they are not written to the tables in the tableView. If instead **comment** `NSData * data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "feedArray"];` **and** `self.feedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];`
(_That are in viewDidLoad_) the data is written **correctly**
2) If I later remove the comments NSData * data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "feedArray"]; the application works and saves the data locally.

Comment: So the problem is in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: I tried to make a check and write `if (date == nil) {} else {self.feedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: date];}`. Nothing, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

**NSUserDefault** support these classes :NSNumber（Integer、Float、Double），NSString，NSDate，NSArray，NSDictionary，BOOL;

**FeedInfo** is a custom class , and you cannot put it in the **NSUserDefault**;

You should turn the **FeedInfo object** to **NSData** , then add it;

```
NSData * newData  = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:newFeed];
[Self.feedArray addObject: newData];
```

Comment: and to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can you this code. my code is help you

Save `NSMutableArray` in `NSUserDefaults`

```
- (void)saveList:(NSMutableArray *)arr
{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:ZIPCODE_LIST];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

Get `NSMutableArray` from `NSUserDefaults`

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getList
{
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:ZIPCODE_LIST];
    NSMutableArray *arr = (NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data];
    return arr;
}
```